# How to check if a string starts with any char value from an array on Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, any, startswith

Suppose that you have the following string:

```
the_string = '[({})]'
```

and suppose that you have the following array:

```
the_array = ['(','[','{']
```

How can you verify that `the_string` starts with any value from `the_array`?

I tried to create something like this:

```
if the_string.startswith(any x in the_array):
   print(True)
else:
   print(False)
```

But, it just didn't work, so I would like to know how could I get the a better approach to the solution (which in this case should be `True`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`any` is a function, so

```py
if any(the_string.startswith(ch) for ch in the_array):
```

If you are only going to print or return `True` or `False` you don't need the `if` and can use the output of `any` directly:

```
print(any(the_string.startswith(ch) for ch in the_array))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert `the_string` to array, after which you do a for ... in loop to each item in the array.

```
list = the_string.split(separator)

for item in list:
    if item in the_array:
        return True
```

Comment: 1. Strings are iterable so it is possible to use `for` on them directly, no need to convert the string to a list. 2. This is far less efficient as it will iterate over the entire string in the worst case

Comment: Also this only checks for entire words where OP wants to compare characters